# Counting files on a remote server with ssh and an expect script

Tags: ssh, scripting, expect

Below is my script to take count for files which are present in remote server.
But it is not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh sduser@172.0.0.2
expect "123"
send "123"
interact
destPath='/archive/Input/ERICIN/AIR/EMG'
dayStamp=`(date --date='1 day ago' '+%Y%m%d')`
if [ -d $destPath ]
then
     cd $destPath
     `cat 'emg_audit_1_'$dayStamp.csv|grep 'ACTPSO_NE_'$dayStamp|wc -l > /home/stsuser/eastregioncount/NEremote$dayStamp.txt`
else
        echo "ERROR: Path $destPath Does not Exists."
fi
```

Comment: why do you have backticks (`) around the cat command?

Comment: Why are you making an extra subshell inside of the backticks on line 8?

Answer (score 2):

To get this to work I would suggest two major changes:

1. use public/private keypairs
2. send commands on the commandline to ssh

You can use `ssh-keygen` to generate a new private-public key pair and use `ssh-copy-id` to install the public key you generate to the new account on `172.0.0.2`.
After that you don't have to go through the `expect "123"` sequence anymore.

That also enables you to call `ssh` with the command on the commandline more easily
(assuming the timezondes on both machines are the same):

```
destPath='/archive/Input/ERICIN/AIR/EMG'
dayStamp=`(date --date='1 day ago' '+%Y%m%d')`
ssh sduser@172.0.0.2 "cd $destPath; cat 'emg_audit_1_'$dayStamp.csv| grep 'ACTPSO_NE_'$dayStamp| wc -l > /home/stsuser/eastregioncount/NEremote$dayStamp.txt"
if [ $? -ne 0 ] 
then 
    echo "ERROR"
fi
```

The cd command already will tell you that $destPath does not exists, no need to echo that yourself. But you can test the exit code and do something more meaningful (than the `echo "Error"`) if necessary.